Android ongoing notification is cancellable
I'm trying to create a notification that should not be cancellable (used in a foreground service), yet the users can swipe it away(Tested on Android 14).
Here is what I've used:
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setAutoCancel(false)

Am I missing something here?


Am I missing something here?

No, insofar as what you describe is documented and expected behavior.
